# Getting the first element that precedes a found element, by a certain condition, with XPath

Tags: xpath, screen-scraping, import.io

Using import.io, given the following snippet, after successfully extracting the `name` and `time` columns, how might one extract the nearest preceding `.heading` element as a third column using XPath?

```
...

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="heading">HBO</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="name">Silicon Valley</div>
    <div class="time">9pm</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="name">The Wire</div>
    <div class="time">10pm</div>
</div>
...
<hr>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="heading">ABC</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="name">Lost</div>
    <div class="time">9pm</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="name">Heroes</div>
    <div class="time">10pm</div>
</div>
...
<hr>

...
```

Comment: Nearest preceding or following `.heading` element?

Comment: @stribizhev The nearest element that comes before the matched data with a class of "heading".

Comment: I removed your regex (hope you can forgive my candor). [Never ever use regular expressions to process (X)HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Besides, even if it _had and an answer_, it would be on conflicting subjects which would be better suited for different questions.

Comment: Try `//div/div[@class='name']/parent::div/preceding-sibling::div/div[@class='heading']/text()`. Tested at http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath. Please check.

Comment: I was just going to post `./parent::div/preceding-sibling::div/div[@class='heading‌​']/text()` but I guess you have got a more expanded answer.

Comment: @stribizhev, using `parent::x/preceding-sibling::y/z` syntax works here but is subtly different from `preceding::z`. If the structure of the document is strictly as given above, there is not much difference, but I'd probably prefer the shorter `preceding::z`. Also, it is good practice that you add `[1]`; though XSLT 1.0 will select the first node, it is not so if you apply templates and in XSLT 2.0 it will select all nodes. Using `[1]` makes the intention clearer ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The nearest element that comes before the matched data with a class of "heading".*

The nearest *preceding* element from a given element can be found with the `preceding` axis in XPath. Suppose we have the expression `div/div[class='name'][. = 'Heroes']`, which selects the last name in your example, the nearest preceding one would be:

```
./preceding::div[@class = 'heading'][1]
```

where `.` is either a genuine context node in which case you can remove `./`, or it should be replaced with the rest of the expression that you already have.

Since the *preceding axis* counts backwards, we just want the first element found. Note that the *preceding axis* does not select ancestors or self nodes, counting from the current node.